# top for web browsers

Tags: browser

This is a bit off the Unix road, but I believe most people interested in the answer are linux or unix users so here goes.

For a long time it seems that the number one process chewing up CPU time and memory is my web browser ( mainly firefox, but others too ). It is true that I have a lot of pages open at once, so I generally don't mind, but recently it's gotten to the point where the browser just bogs down the system, and when I close some pages some sanity is restored.

What would be nice is if there were some tool or plugin that would tell me exactly what web pages/sites are using the most resources.

Comment: Related browser-specific question: http://superuser.com/questions/263605/how-to-findout-which-firefox-tab-is-using-most-cpu-or-memory

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many pages are we talking about here?  5 or 100?

Comment: @Dylan, about between 100 and 500.

Comment: Wow! I was being sarcastic when I said 100. Why don't you use tab groups and favorites... That is a lot of resources wasted it seems. Perhaps I'm missing something

Answer (score 8):

### Firefox

1. It's not pretty, but go to `about:memory?verbose` in your browser.

   - You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search for URLs.

### Chrome | Chromium

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> or use the menu: More Tools → Task Manager